# Configuring DNAT with multiple ISP interfaces

Tags: port-forwarding, iptables

I've configured Ubuntu pc as a router and confused with rules for DNAT with multiple input interfaces. When I'm trying to ping *ISP-1 IP* the router answers from external_p, and for *ISP-2 IP* from external_s. But when I'm opening *ISP-1 IP*:80 or *ISP-2 IP*:80 it answers from external_p for both IPs. How can I configure it answer to DNAT using interface which is received request?

```
ip rule show
0:  from all lookup local
300:    from <ISP-1 IP> lookup external_p
400:    from <ISP-2 IP> lookup external_s
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

ip route
default via <ISP-1 GW> dev vlan_ext_p metric 100
default via <ISP-2 GW> dev vlan_ext_s metric 200

ip route show table external_p
default via <ISP-1 GW> dev vlan_ext_p proto static
ip route show table external_s
default via <ISP-2 GW> dev vlan_ext_s proto static

iptables-save
*nat
-A PREROUTING -i vlan_ext_p -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.4.2
-A PREROUTING -i vlan_ext_s -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.4.2
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.16.0.0/12 -o vlan_ext_p -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.16.0.0/12 -o vlan_ext_s -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT

*filter
-A FORWARD -d 172.17.4.2/32 -i vlan_ext_p -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 172.17.4.2/32 -i vlan_ext_s -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A FORWARD -s 172.16.0.0/12 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rules

```
300:    from <ISP-1 IP> lookup external_p
400:    from <ISP-2 IP> lookup external_s
```

works because reply packets have `src` IP = `dst` IP of incoming packets (but not the same outgoing interface) and routed via different interfaces by these rules.

With DNAT you effictively broke this behavior by changing `dst` adderss to the same 172.17.4.2 for packets with dport 80 arrived to both ISP1-IP and ISP2-IP. So all outgoing replies **from local processes with sport 80** have src 172.17.4.2  and your source routing rules doesnt work anymore for **outgoing** packets related to these **incoming connections**.

And these packets further routed using default route with minimum metric in main table.

You do not change `dst` for icmp incoming packets with DNAT so ping replies routed via appropriate interfaces.

You should use iptables to mark incoming **connections** (not just packets) with connmark **before doing DNAT**, copy connmark to packet's mark for outgoing packets and route connection's reply packets with `fwmark` selector instead `from` selector.

```
# loose reverse path check since kernel ignores fwmark doing this check
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.vlan_ext_p.rp_filter = 2
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.vlan_ext_s.rp_filter = 2

# mark incoming connections
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -i vlan_ext_s -d isp2-ip -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j CONNMARK --set-mark 2
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -i vlan_ext_p -d isp1-ip -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j CONNMARK --set-mark 1

# for reply traffic copy connection's mark into packet's mark because policy rules use packet's mark
# after this outgoing packets will have packet's mark corresponded to marks of incoming connections
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -s 172.16.0.0/12 -m connmark ! --mark 0 -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -s 172.16.0.0/12 -m connmark ! --mark 0 -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
iptables -t mangle -I OUTPUT -m connmark ! --mark 0 -j CONNMARK --restore-mark

# route packets using packet's mark
ip rule add fwmark 2 table external_s
ip rule add fwmark 1 table external_p
ip rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0
```

Obviously you use some http application in a docker container.

So second option is let your application just directly listen on host's interfaces or let container have two addresses so all works with source routing as is.

Comment: Thank you!  
Looks like really what I need but still don't work :(  
I also tried any other interpretations for iptables like PREROUTING instead of INPUT, and enabling rp_filter, fwmark_reflect for test purpose, or adding local routes to external_p and external_s tables.  
iptables shows packets for CONNMARK but answer still coming from default route in main table.
What do you think could I have missed in this case?

Comment: Try updated rules. I forgot about forwarded traffic

Comment: Hi! I've added updated rules but it's still answer using default gateway and there is no packets in "-A FORWARD -o vlan_ext_s -m connmark ! --mark 0 -j CONNMARK --restore-mark" rule (iptables --list -nv -t mangle)

Comment: Replace FORWARD -o blahbla with PREROUTING -s 172.16.0.0/12 so connection marks restored before first routing decision

Comment: Thank you very much!! It works now :)
Is it okay to remove "-d isp-ip" from first two rules?

Comment: You maybe think dst checks here are overkill. Yes, in current configuration they dont strictly needed. But if interface would be assigned more then one ip it will work maybe not how you want. Another issue is security. You may recieve packet on any interface with ANY dst ip not just with ip assigned to interface. It's a rule of thumb but almost nobody cares about   that. Also it doesnt helps in performance.